# Failure on importing mlflow to Azure Databricks 7.3 LTS ML Runtime

Tags: python, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am having trouble trying to import mlflow to Azure databricks. I'm currently using 7.3 LTS ML Runtime, which already have mlflow==1.11.0. I am a developing data scientist and I have no clue how to solve this issue. Have already tried to reinstall and didn't suceed. Any thoughts?

This is the error message:

```
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint hyperdrive = azureml.train.hyperdrive:HyperDriveRun._from_run_dto with exception (azureml-core 1.8.0.post1 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-core~=1.19.0'), {'azureml-telemetry'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint automl = azureml.train.automl.run:AutoMLRun._from_run_dto with exception (azureml-core 1.8.0.post1 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-core~=1.19.0'), {'azureml-telemetry'}).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.PipelineRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:PipelineRun._from_dto with exception (azureml-core 1.8.0.post1 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-core~=1.19.0')).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.ReusedStepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_reused_dto with exception (azureml-core 1.8.0.post1 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-core~=1.19.0')).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.StepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_dto with exception (azureml-core 1.8.0.post1 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('azureml-core~=1.19.0')).
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.scriptrun = azureml.core.script_run:ScriptRun._from_run_dto with exception (msrest 0.6.18 (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('msrest>=0.6.21'), {'azure-mgmt-containerregistry'}).
Could not import from mlflow. Please upgrade to Mlflow 1.4.0 or higher.
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/utils.py:123: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "adbazureml": No module named 'mlflow.store.rest_store'
  _tracking_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
Could not import from mlflow. Please upgrade to Mlflow 1.4.0 or higher.
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/utils.py:123: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "azureml": No module named 'mlflow.store.rest_store'
  _tracking_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
Could not import from mlflow. Please upgrade to Mlflow 1.4.0 or higher.
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_model_registry/utils.py:106: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register store for scheme "azureml": No module named 'mlflow.store.rest_store'
  _model_registry_store_registry.register_entrypoints()
Could not import from mlflow. Please upgrade to Mlflow 1.4.0 or higher.
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repository_registry.py:89: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register artifact repository for scheme "adbazureml": No module named 'mlflow.store.rest_store'
  _artifact_repository_registry.register_entrypoints()
Could not import from mlflow. Please upgrade to Mlflow 1.4.0 or higher.
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repository_registry.py:89: UserWarning: Failure attempting to register artifact repository for scheme "azureml": No module named 'mlflow.store.rest_store'
  _artifact_repository_registry.register_entrypoints()
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py:546: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working
  class IteratorBase(collections.Iterator, trackable.Trackable,
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-818c9387-555f-4b61-a142-d3c244a68503/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/testing.py:21: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp

pip list

azure-common              1.1.28           
azure-core                1.24.1           
azure-graphrbac           0.61.1           
azure-identity            1.4.1            
azure-mgmt-authorization  0.61.0           
azure-mgmt-containerregistry 10.0.0        
azure-mgmt-core           1.3.1            
azure-mgmt-keyvault       2.2.0            
azure-mgmt-network        10.2.0           
azure-mgmt-resource       11.0.0           
azure-mgmt-storage        11.2.0           
azure-storage-blob        12.4.0           
azureml-automl-core       1.19.0           
azureml-core              1.8.0.post1      
azureml-dataprep          2.6.6            
azureml-dataprep-native   26.0.0           
azureml-dataprep-rslex    1.4.0            
azureml-dataset-runtime   1.19.0.post1     
azureml-mlflow            1.8.0            
azureml-pipeline          1.19.0           
azureml-pipeline-core     1.19.0           
azureml-pipeline-steps    1.19.0           
azureml-sdk               1.19.0           
azureml-telemetry         1.19.0           
azureml-train             1.19.0           
azureml-train-automl-client 1.19.0         
azureml-train-core        1.19.0           
azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive 1.19.0
mlflow                    1.11.0
pip                       20.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed latest version of mlflow i.e. `mlflow 1.26.1` and it worked for me.

You can resolve this issue by upgrading from version `1.11.0` to `1.26.1`

[image]

[image]